# how to get Value AND ID from a checkbox in a loop using php?

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to get the values and ID's of all checked checkboxes after a submit.
The loop I have now works and retrieves all checked checkboxes, and I can do an echo of all there values.
But I also need to get the ID at the same time, how can I do that ?

I found many answers here but they all only retrieve the Value and never the ID, I need them both.

My checkboxes are setup like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1778" id="HT1234">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1946" id="HT4567">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1609" id="HT9876">
```

and my current loop is this :

```
$values = "";
if (!empty($_POST['cbTrucks'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['cbTrucks'] as $checkbox) 
    {
        if ($values == "")
            $values = $checkbox;
        else
            $values = $values.",".$checkbox;
    }

    echo $values;
}
else
{
    echo "filter is empty";
}
```

This display the values of all selected checkboxes, but I also wont the ID's

Something like

```
$values = "";
$ids = "";
if (!empty($_POST['cbTrucks'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['cbTrucks'] as $checkbox) 
    {
        if ($values == "")
            $values = $checkbox;
        else
            $values = $values.",".$checkbox;

        $ids = $ids.$checkbox.id; // I need something like this
    }

    echo $values;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because IDs are not submitted in POST by default. What I suggest is that you add the IDs to the values as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1778_HT1234">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1946_HT4567">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[]" value="1609_HT9876">
```

Then use in PHP:

```
list($value, $id) = explode('_', $checkbox);
```

In the loop:

```
foreach($_POST['cbTrucks'] as $checkbox) {
   list($value, $id) = explode('_', $checkbox);
}
```

Comment: That is my current plan to do it like this, I just hoped there was a more elegant way to do this. Thanks

Comment: @GuidoG Not unless you use JavaScript

Comment: yes but than I think this is still more elegant. Mixing js and php is not always easy and I am new to both

Comment: does the List creates two arrays that I can loop or how exact do I use this ?

Comment: You could also use the `id` as the key in the `name`, e.g. `<input type="checkbox" name="cbTrucks[HT1234]" value="1778" />` then you can grab both with a simple `foreach($_REQUEST['cbTrucks'] as $key => $value)` type loop.

Comment: list() captures two variables that result from exploding the string in two pieces.

Comment: @CD001 How can I use that do you have an example

Comment: Thank you I am implementing it now

Comment: @CD001 I tried your suggestion and it also works. If you post it as an answer I wil upvote it